# Does CIDetector For other Barcode Types

Tags: swift, barcode, cidetector

I am looking at CIDetectorTypeQRCode. How can I detect other types of barcodes? I can read other barcode types via AVMetadataObjectType, however I want to do the same with CIDetector. I am trying to achieve real time highlighting of the barcode.

Trying for a sort of zoom in effect before my AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate achieves a full lock and read of the code.

Answer (score 0):

CIDetector has only following types to detect, So we can't use it to detect another type of barcodes.

- `CIDetectorTypeFace`
- `CIDetectorTypeRectange`
- `CIDetectorTypeQRCode`
- `CIDetectorTypeText`

But since iOS 11 has introduced a new set of [Vision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) API's. Now it is possible to read barcodes from an image.

if you are targeting >iOS 11,  you can use `VNDetectBarcodesRequest` to read barcode results.